# How can i make a link do some jquery then go to destination

Tags: jquery

I have a link in a page that I need to do some jquery on before I go to the destination page.  Im sure there are dozens of ways to do this, what is most recommended?

```js
$('#link').click(function(){
alert('you clicked'); 
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href='google.com' id='link'>Google</a>
```

obviously fails.  thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('you clicked'); 
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Set the location after doing whatever you want to do.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault(); // this stops the url from being loaded
    // do whatever js you want to here
    alert('you clicked'); 
    // then send the user on their way
    window.location.href = $(this).attr('href');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do the following:

- Disable the default behavior by using `event.preventDefault`.
- Do what you wish to do.
- Redirect.

Something like this:

```
$('#link').on('click', function(event)
{
    event.preventDefault(); 
    // Do something
    // ...
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    location.location.href = url;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

To change the url there is no need for jquery

```
  document.getElementById('link').href = 'new url here'
```

However if you want to do something onClick first, you'll need to prevent the default action

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault():
    // do what ever you need here
    window.location.href = 'new url here';
});
```