# How can i make a link do some jquery then go to destination with a new target

Tags: jquery, href

I followed this post and it works fine:

[How can i make a link do some jquery then go to destination](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28028715/how-can-i-make-a-link-do-some-jquery-then-go-to-destination)

How can i add the equivalent to target=”_blank”?

I want the destination page to open in a new tab

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JavaScript: location.href to open in new window/tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5141910/javascript-location-href-to-open-in-new-window-tab)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `window.open` ike this:

```
window.open('url/to/page', '_blank');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `window.open` as following

```
$('#link').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    alert('you clicked'); 
    window.open($(this).attr('href'),'_blank');
});
```

The first parameter will get url from anchor tag `href` attribute and then second will add target `_blank` property.